# perl + uniq characters before variable

Tags: linux, files, perl

What is the meaning of the characters "%%" before the variable EOF ?

```
  $LINE =`tail -1 $FILE `;
  chomp($LINE);
  if ($LINE eq "%%EOF") 
      {

        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: What's that about `uniq` in the title?

Comment: uniq - is about "%%" characters

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but the most common use of `%%EOF` is in PDF files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No particular meaning, they're just treated literally. It just checks whether the last line contains exactly `%%EOF`. That happens to be the end marker in PostScript or PDF documents (try `tail -n 1 somefile.pdf`).

`perl` expands scalar (`$var`) and list (`@list`) variables inside double quotes but not hashes/associative arrays (`%hash`).

Note that that code is incorrect in that

```
$LINE = `tail -1 $FILE`;
```

should be:

```
$LINE = `tail -n 1 -- $FILE`;
```

or:

```
$ENV{FILE} = $FILE;
$LINE = `tail -n 1 < "\$FILE"`;
#or# $LINE = qx'tail -n 1 < "$FILE"';
```

You need `--` to make sure the content of `$FILE` is not taken as an option (for instance if it starts with `-` or `+`). The redirection approach would also prevent problems with a file called `-` (which if passed as argument would be understood by `tail` as meaning *standard input* instead of the file called `-` in the current directory) but would mean a shell has to be invoked.

Comment: it's also not very good perl code.  perl doesn't need to run `tail` to get the last line of a file, it can do everything that `tail` does all by itself (and more).  There's even a `File::Tail` module for `tail -F` style file-following.  And fixed strings like `%%EOF` don't need double-quotes, single-quotes are better.

Comment: @cas, `File::Tail` is not meant to be used to get the last line of a file. Getting the last line of a file reliably and efficiently (without reading the whole file if it can be avoided) independently of the file type (think non-seekable files) is not trivial.

Comment: i know what File::Tail is for, i even mentioned it in my comment.  OP's code gets the last line of a file ("$FILE"), not a pipe.   `open(FH,"<",$FILE);while (<FH>) { next unless eof; $LINE = $_} ; close(FH)`.  for very long files, could be optimised by seeking to, e.g., filesize-1000 bytes (or 10000 or some other reasonable guess, based on possible/probable line length).